# Using custom icons on left and right in jquery mobile list

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out how to add custom icons on the left and right side of a list item. I found this example (see link and code below) but if you notice the icon does not show up, it's just an empty circle.  At first I thought it was because the link was invalid but I tried it on my page with my own image but the same thing happened.  Unfortunately I only have a reputation of 13 so I am not allowed to post pictures, however here is a sample of how I would like the li item to have icons on both ends.

-*****************************-
| icon_left  TEXT    icon_right |
 -*****************************-

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-icon-myapp-smiley {
background-image: url(http://swiftthemes.com/forums/images/icons/icon6.png) !important;
}
</style>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="myapp-smiley"><a href="#">My LI!!!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Code on jsfiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/KYaQT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM 1.0.1 is quite old and outdated now. You should upgrade to 1.4 and jQuery 1.9 or greater.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
    <li data-icon="myicon"><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon-myicon2 ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>Text in list item 1</a></li>
</ul>

.ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("http://people.mozilla.org/~shorlander/files/australis-linux-svg-test/images-linux/toolbarButton-bookmark.svg");
}
.ui-icon-myicon2:after {
    background-image: url("http://forum.librecad.org/images/gear.png");
}
.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

For the icon on the right you had the correct approach. Set the `data-icon` attribute on the `<LI>`. In jQM 1.4, the CSS uses the pseudo :after element for the background image.

To add an icon on the left, you can put a span inline with the text and add CSS to position it.

[image: listItem icons right and left]

If you don't want the gray disk behind the icon, set the background color transparent:

```
.ui-icon-myicon2:after {
    background-image: url("http://forum.librecad.org/images/gear.png");
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uhbrt7mL/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much =) I wanted to vote up your response but it says I need a reputation of 15.  One last question,  I was trying to format the text on the list divider to match the header however it just didn't work.  Here is my css code for the header h1 and the divider.

h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #B2C2D1;
}

.ui-li-divider {
   color: #FFFFFF !important;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px #B2C2D1;
   background: #2F4F4F !important;
   text-align: center !important;
}

Comment: @speedracer2003, your divider css seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uhbrt7mL/2/ P.S., I upvoted your question, so you have reputation now ;)